SwiftData - how to correctly update application when SwiftData Model(s) change?
would anybody be so kind to provide a link or "steps to follow" that need to be done when you change a model and you want the updated app releases not to crash?
Whenever I make a change to the model, I need to reinstall the app. If I don't the app crashes whenever it tries to access the "new value" from the model changed.
Thank you.

The word you’re looking for is migration if you need to search for more information but start with SwiftData By Example that has some good information about this topic

thx, I will check it out. Libor

Some simple changes like adding or removing a property are handled automatically (lightweight migration).
When you rename a property or relationship you can use this:
@Attribute(originalName: "name")
let firstName: String // Renamed from "name" to "firstName".

For more advanced migrations there's "complex migration".
Source and more information: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10195/?time=330
